# ISAPI rewrite products

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi

I need mod_rewrite functionality on an IIS .NET server. Is http://www.isapirewrite.com/ the best option? It seems to have the largest documentation/user base. I also see codeplex.com/IIRF , this is free but comments mention it has a different syntax from .htaccess? I am very unfamiliar with IS .NET and would like to mimic Apache .htaccess, please advise.

I will be 301 redirecting, as well as canonicalizing urls.

I also see both ISAPI_Rewrite 2 and 3 both being sold for the same price. Why might I consider 2?

Thank you so much for your time, thoughts and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) it has almost identical syntax to mod_rewrite (see http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/compatibility.htm).

I've used it on a number of sites and am very happy with its performance and ease of use.

Josh

Comment: Josh

I'm having trouble installing the free version of ISAPI_Rewrite 2. Check my post on their forum here: http://www.helicontech.com/forum/forum_posts-TID-13475-PN-1-TPN-1.htm

Answer (score 2):

IIRF supports *most* of the same syntax as mod_rewrite's .htaccess, but some things are missing.

It works well .

The price is right.